# Bibtex citation crashed the document, now I can't run any document with a bibliography

Tags: bibtex

I don't even know where to start. My document was running fine until I added a citation to my bibtex file that crashed the bibliography. This has happened before, and I've been able to copy the contents of the latex file to a new .tex file, and create a new .bib file by copying over the citations that worked.

But this time when I copy over the .tex file it still crashes (without the bad reference). I've deleted all of the original copies of EVERYTHING, reinstalled mikTex and TexStudio. Emptied the recycle bin. The only thing I kept were the figures I needed, and I copied over the latex content to a brand new file (same with bibliography). I've also tried creating a document with only on reference and a .bib file with just that reference. That doesn't run either. I don't know what part of my code to give because it's a fairly large document....

Any help will be so so so appreciated.

EDIT: I apologize for the lack of code. I was kind of overwhelmed. I'm not sure why, but what worked for me was deleting, then re-typing all of the \cite{authoryear} commands within the document. This was after I had copied over the document contents to a new file, and also created a new .bib with the references that worked. I have no idea why this was successful. Any input?

Comment: Welcome to the tex stack community. We don't do black magic in here to figure out the actual cause of your problem. Please provide us with the actual code or at least provide us with a minimal working example that actually generates the error. Otherwise, you're risking your post to be closed or put on hold.

Comment: Welcome, does a simple *helli world* example run? If not, why? Errors? Did you remove the aux files?

Comment: If you don't know what a MWE is, see here: [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407).

Comment: You wrote, "I've also tried creating a document with only on[e] reference and a .bib file with just that reference. That doesn't run either." Well, if your document compiles correctly *without* that particular `\cite` instruction, then that instruction must be the main problem, right? Please post a minimal LaTeX file with just the `\cite` directive in question, along with a minimal bib file that contains just the bibliographic entry you're trying to cite. The objective, for now, is to come up with a reproducible error.

Comment: Probably Just a Glitch in The  Matrix.

Comment: Did your brand new files actually have new names. I've seen cases before of people renaming the original to something like myfile.tex.old and creating a new myfile.tex. That wouldn't help if auxiliary files were part of the problem as the old ones would still be found

Comment: @ChrisH I named them differently. Started with "Coinfection1" and ended up at "Coinfection5" before it worked. I even changed the .bib file names in the same way when I copied over the content to new files.

Comment: @Johannes_B Honestly, that's how I feel. It seemed like total black magic to me.

Comment: @ChrisH Half of me wants to try to replicate the problem with the backup I had saved before the crash, by adding the bad reference to that .bib as well. But the other half of me is terrified it will mess up the whole system again.